# how to set TextField automatically editible without clicking Textfield on qtquick2

Tags: qml, textfield, qtquick2

i am trying to create a TextField and when the TextField is appeared i want it to become editible even without clicking the Text area. It appears but without clicking on placeholder text which is text area, it is not becoming active. Here is what i tried

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    TextField {
        id: textFieldTest
        placeholderText: "This area should appear as clicked"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        focus: true
        Component.onCompleted: textFieldTest.forceActiveFocus()
    }
}
```

I've also tried to use

```
focus: true
```

and

```
Component.onCompleted: textFieldTest.forceActiveFocus()
```

seperately. Also together. But both of them did not work. Which function or feature should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, you need to delay it, e.g.

```
    Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(textFieldTest.forceActiveFocus)
```

The reason being, is that other components initializing may also want to change focus. So, you want to delay your request for focus so that "last in wins".

Comment: That was the solution of my question, it worked really fine. Thank you so much Stephen!

Answer (score 0):

Please share your entire code if possible. It seems some thing else is stealing the focus. In my case this is working:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TextField {
         id: textFieldTest
         placeholderText: "This area should appear as clicked"
         anchors.centerIn: parent
         focus: true
         Component.onCompleted: textFieldTest.forceActiveFocus()
     }
}
```